# Python: Parsing a single-line JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a large one-line JSON file and can't seem to figure it out. I've looked for resources on here and elsewhere, but most of what I see tells you to parse everything line-by-line. Since I'm working with one really long line, what's the best way to parse this with python?

Specifically, I'm looking for one particular value that's in a nested dictionary in the JSON data. The data looks like this (after running it through a formatter):

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"wells.529038",
         "geometry":null,
         "properties":{
            "api":"4245180382"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"wells.481699",
         "geometry":null,
         "properties":{
            "api":"4237182573"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to extract all the api values, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do that given the multi-nested structure and because the file is huge and only one line. What the best approach here?

Comment: There's a [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module since python 2.6, use it...

Comment: you can do: `import json` and then `json.load(open('my_file.json'))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard library :

```
json_data = json.loads(your_line)

# Usage exemple
for feature in json_data['features']:
    print feature['id']
```

Comment: I was doing this but nesting another loop with `for property in feature["properties"]`, but doing `print property["api"]` gave me an error "string indices must be integers". If I just use the one loop and do `print feature["properties"]["api"]` it works great though. Thanks!